# How to make this simple regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to make a string starts and ends with alphanumeric range between 5 to 20 characters and it could have a space or none between characters. `/^[a-z\s?A-Z0-9]{5,20}$/` but this is not working.

**EDIT**
test test -should pass
testtest -should pass
test test test -should not pass

Comment: no, because I want one space or none

Comment: still, remove the question mark

Comment: then do `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]\s?){5,20}$/`, but this could imply that the string ends with a space

Comment: oYes - I don't think the question mark behaves like you think it behaves while in a character class.

Comment: @devNull: yes I know, I think it's just the pseudo code, because I don't know the right code yet

Comment: Ahh sorry. I didn't realize is was pseudo code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this with traditional regex without writing a ridiculously long expression, so you need to use a look-ahead:

```
/^(?=(\w| ){15,20}$)\w+ ?\w+$/
```

This says, make sure there are between 15 and 20 characters in the match, then match `/\w+ \w+/`

**Note** I used \w for simplification. It is the same as your character class above *except* it also accepts underscores. If you don't want to match them you have to do:

```
/^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{15,20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Oh, that is clever, I haven't been exposed to lookaheads not used at the end of patterns. +1

Comment: The `15` should be a `5` yes? Also, the lookahead can be reduced to: `(?=.{5,20}$)` Here's how I'd write it: `/^(?=.{5,20}$)\w+(?: \w+)?$/`

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a `?` inside of `[...]`. `[...`] is used to specify a set of characters precisely, you can't maybe (`?`) have a character inside a set of characters. The occurrence of any specific characters is already optional, the `?` is meaningless.

If you allow any number of spaces inside your match, just remove the question mark. If you want to allow a single space but no more, then regular expressions alone can't do that for you, you'd need something like

```
if (myString.match(/^[a-z\sA-Z0-9]{5,20}$/ && myString.match(/\s/g).length <= 1)
```

You couldn't do this with a single traditional regex without it being dozens of lines long; regexes are meant for matching more simpler patterns than this.

If you only want to use regexes, you could use two instead of one. The first matches the general pattern, the second ensures that only one non-space characters is found.

```
if (myString.match(/^[a-z\sA-Z0-9]{5,20}$/ && myString.match(/^[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*$/))) {
```

---

#### Example Usage

```
inputs = ["test test", "testtest", "test test test"];

for (index in inputs) {
    var myString = inputs[index];
    if (myString.match(/^[a-z\sA-Z0-9]{5,20}$/ && myString.match(/^[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*$/))) {
        console.log(myString + " matches.")
    } else {
        console.log(myString + " does not match.")
    }
}
```

This produces the output specified in your question.

Comment: That's a nice solution, but I want it included inside the regexp

Comment: @oYes It cannot be done using a single regular expression without it being hundreds of lines long. regexes aren't designed for more complicated grammars like that. I've added a way to do it using *two* regular expressions.

Comment: It's true, to do it with a traditional regex you would have to write a big OR clause accounting for the space being in each position like: `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{15,20}|[a-zA-Z0-9] [a-zA-Z0-9]{14,19}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2} [a-zA-Z0-9]{13,18}| ... etc`

Answer (score -1):

Meh , So here's the ridiculously long traditional regex for the same

```
(?i)[a-z0-9]+( [a-z0-9]+)?{5,12}
```

js vesrion (w/o the nested quantifier)

```
/^([a-z0-9]( [a-z0-9])?){5,12}$/i
```

Comment: What language is this for? Perl gives me an error for "nested quantifiers in regex", JavaScript for "nothing to repeat", and Python raises `sre_constants.error: multiple repeat`.

Comment: Java . (?i) is the case-insensitive flag , use one for the language you use .

Comment: I adjusted appropriately. I think the engines were objecting to `?{5,12}`.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think it's because it doesn't work with javascript(as you can see I didn't tag java) even without the flag.. maybe I'm too stupid to use this on JS, but if you can give a javascript example, that'd be cool